# I want to sort this list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to sort below list

Current output:

```
+ Q1-2015
+ Q1-2016
+ Q1-2017
+ Q1-2018
+ Q1-2019
+ Q2-2015
+ Q2-2016
+ Q2-2017
+ Q2-2018
+ Q2-2019
```

Expected output :

```
+ Q1-2015
+ Q2-2015
+ Q3-2015
+ Q4-2015
+ Q1-2016
+ Q2-2016
+ Q3-2016
+ Q4-2016
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: Use substring to get the year, order by that first and then order by the whole thing.  2 levels of order by, the first using a substring function to get the year.

Answer (score 4):

You could sort by the quarter and year components in two separate levels:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    RIGHT(col, 4),  -- sort first by year component
    LEFT(col, 2);   -- then sort by quarter within a given year
```

### Demo

Comment: Why isn't it "working" @MohideenAsraf; it looks to me like it does.

Comment: Not a realistic edge case; a year only ever has four quarters in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring`, `charindex` and `len` functions together with the logic splitting upto hyphen and after hyphen, and better to cast as int for proper ordering for other cases (*even if no need for only four quarters as in this case*):

```
 order by cast(substring(col0,2,charindex('-',col0)-2) as int),
          cast(substring(col0,charindex('-',col0)+1,len(col0)) as int)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6cc79d002b096c255451164b2192d0a3)</kbd>